Why does Blazor virtualization exaggerate the height of a web page?
I have a Blazor web page using MudBlazor, but MudSelect does not support virtualization. If I use a foreach loop to load the entire list, it causes the webpage to lag. Therefore, I turned to Blazor virtualization. Everything worked fine until I discovered that virtualization caused my webpage to have an abnormal height, often being tens to hundreds of times the original height, with the extra length being entirely blank. If I use Take to retrieve a small number of items, it works fine, but in this case, virtualization becomes useless because with such a small number of items, foreach works well, and I can even use a SelectAll box with the loop. Is there a way to fix this virtualization issue?
<MudSelect Variant="Variant.Outlined" Margin="Margin.Dense" T="string" MultiSelection="true" @bind-SelectedValues="@list" Adornment="Adornment.End">
    <Virtualize Items="users">
        <MudSelectItem Value="@context.id"/>
    </Virtualize>
</MudSelect>
@code{
    IEnumerable<string> list = new HashSet<string>();
    IEnumerable<string> users = new HashSet<string>();
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        HashSet<string> hashSet = new HashSet<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            hashSet.Add(i.ToString());
        }
        users = hashSet;
    }
}


A workaround can be found here: https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/6545 . The SelectAll isn't working properly there. If you want to use it you would have to implement your own selectall

If your read the docs it says that if you use the virtualization you should set a fixed sized container. The code does queries to calculate the size of the spacers for the scrollbar to operate. Without a fixed size it goes haywire. There are ways to fix the size of the container without using a set px value using grids etc. Also set use a fixed sized container per row for the same reasons.

@Uerschel Your fix didn't work for me.

@BrianParker In my site MudSelect is inside a MudPaper with a fixed height of 26vh, and this problem still occurs

Turns out for it to work the fixed area has to be right before the MudSelect, in my case it was MudPaper > MudGrid > MudSelect changed to MudPaper > MudGrid > div (with fixed height) > MudSelect and it worked perfectly. Thanks for the reply.

Add a  like this around the MudSelect and the problem is fixed:
<div style="height:55px;overflow-y:hidden;">
   //MudSelect here
</div>

